# How to POST a Json Object from c# client to Python API in the server?

Tags: c#, python, json, azure, flask

I am trying to send a JSON data from C# (using JObject) to Python Flask APIs. Whenever I test this in the localhost, the python API is able to read the data as JSON. But when the code is deployed in the server, it is not able to read the data and is breaking. C# code is deployed in IIS in an Azure VM and Python is deployed as a Microservice in Azure. What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to communicate between the two languages instead of JSON. You can find the code snippets below:

C#:

```
string personjson = HttpContext.Request.Form["personinfo"]
var json = JObject.Parse(personjson);

_client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new 
Uri("http://mypythonapi.azurewebsites.net") };
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();              
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("/insertPersonNode", 
json);
var message = response.IsSuccessStatusCode ? "Data posted" : $"Failed to post data. Status code:{response.StatusCode}";
```

Python:

```
@app.route('/insertPersonNode', methods=['POST'])
def insertPersonNode():
    try:        
        UserName = request.authorization['username']
        Password = request.authorization['password']
        userLoginNode = userAuthentication(UserName, Password)
        data = request.json
```

Comment: could you provide the error details?

Comment: That's the issue, I am not able to see the error in the server logs. All I know is it is breaking while reading the data.

Comment: have you tried to run it in debug mode ?

Comment: @Prometheus Yes, I tried running it in debug mode and this is the error I am getting: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution to this issue. Using PostAsync instead of PostAsJsonAsync worked for me.

```
var response = await _client.PostAsync("/insertPersonNode", new StringContent(personjson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```